# Confused results in my OpenMP code using task clause

Tags: multithreading, task, openmp

I am new to using the `task` clause in OpenMP and I am not sure if I have understood the meaning of it correctly. Here is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

void task(int p)
{
    printf("Thread ID: %d, task: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), p); 
}

#define N       5    
int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{
    int i;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    {   
#pragma omp single 
        {   
            for(i = 0;i < N; i++)
            {   
            #pragma omp task 
                task(i);
            }   
        }   
    }   
return 0;
}
```

I use the Intel 16.0 compiler to compile my code and expect to get the output like this:

```
- Thread ID: 0, task: 0  
- Thread ID: 2, task: 4
- Thread ID: 2, task: 3 
- Thread ID: 0, task: 1 
- Thread ID: 1, task: 2
```

However, the actually output of this code is:

```
- Thread ID: 0, task: 5  
- Thread ID: 2, task: 5
- Thread ID: 2, task: 5 
- Thread ID: 0, task: 5 
- Thread ID: 1, task: 5
```

The output of 'task:' is fixed to be 5 instead of ranging from 0 to 4 which is not what I expected to be. Can anyone help me to understand this result?

Comment: I have also tried the gcc 4.4.7 compiler , the result is similar to the Intel compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're observing is due to the variable visibility. I have rerun your application while compiling it for gcc 4.8.4 and icc 16.0.3 and I got the following results (which vary across executions):

**gcc**

```
Thread ID: 2, task: 1
Thread ID: 2, task: 5
Thread ID: 2, task: 5
Thread ID: 1, task: 5
Thread ID: 0, task: 2
```

**icc**

```
Thread ID: 0, task: 5
Thread ID: 1, task: 3
Thread ID: 1, task: 5
Thread ID: 0, task: 5
Thread ID: 2, task: 5
```

Since visibility of variable `i` is not declared in the `#pragma omp` construct the compiler decides that `i` should be declared as `shared`, which means that modifications done by any thread are observed by the remaining threads.

In your case, since you expect messages being printed showing task 0 to 4, that means that each thread should have its `private` copy of `i`, as in the following code -- which derives from yours. Notice the modification in the `#pragma omp parallel`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

void task(int p)
{
  printf("Thread ID: %d, task: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), p);
}

#define N       5
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i;
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3) private(i)
  {
    #pragma omp single
    {
      for(i = 0;i < N; i++)
      {
        #pragma omp task
        task(i);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The result of this version, no matter the compiler you use, is:

```
Thread ID: 2, task: 1
Thread ID: 2, task: 3
Thread ID: 2, task: 4
Thread ID: 1, task: 0
Thread ID: 0, task: 2
```

*NOTE* that the placement of `private` can either go into the `#pragma omp parallel` construct, or as user smateo suggests, it can go into the `#pragma omp task` (but in the latter case as `firstprivate` to keep the value of the variable when going into the `task` construct). The actual decision on where it goes depends on the semantics of your application.

Comment: May I suggest you then to accept / upvote any of our answers? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the implicit data-sharing of `i` in the task construct.

If I recall correctly, `i` is determined to be shared in the task construct because this variable is implicitly determined to  be shared in the parallel, but perhaps i'm wrong. Assuming that I'm right, your code generates a race-condition since the task is capturing `&i` rather than the value of `i`. Note that `i` is passed by value once the task is executed (and potentially the value of `i` can be 5).

My advice: if you are not sure about the implicit data-sharing of a variable, make it always explicit. In your case, annotate the task with `firstprivate(i)`